# How to keep mouse cursor hidden in neovim + tmux when switching to NeoVim?

Tags: linux, tmux, neovim

I can't figure out what is causing this issue, and if it is the fault of NeoVIM or `tmux` (or both).

Components:

- Manjaro Linux
- Konsole
- NeoVim
- Tmux

Reproduce:

- Create multiple tabs/panes in Tmux (ctrl-b c multiple times)
- Open NeoVim in one of the panes
- Put mouse cursor in middle of terminal
- Go to a non-neovim pane and type some commands
- Mouse cursor gets properly hidden and doesn't reappear
- Using tmux, switch to the pane that contains neovim
- Mouse cursor appears (even though it wasn't touched) and does not disappear no matter how much I type, UNLESS: I move the mouse a small amount, THEN press a keyboard key again.

I strongly feel that this is a neovim issue because I couldn't reproduce the issue using nano.

Answer (score 0):

At least for now I have a workaround -- probably something that would benefit being built-in to KDE but I digress:

I installed the [Unclutter utility](https://github.com/Airblader/unclutter-xfixes) which runs globally and auto hides the mouse cursor after inactivity. I have a hunch (based on the X11 name) that this won't work in Wayland though.